# python: How to lookup product data from amazon

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I am trying the python-amazon-product-api lib to access data about amazon products. My code looks like this:

I am trying to make a lookup of product by it's ASIN to get data like: Title, Images, Description. So far getting following error:

```
In [57]: result = api.item_lookup(id = 'B007R07BK8')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/oleg/Documents/<ipython-input-57-d3516809d324> in <module>()
----> 1 result = api.item_lookup(id = 'B007R07BK8')

TypeError: item_lookup() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
In [58]:
```

Need an advice about what I am doing wrong

Comment: Well, your error is this: `item_lookup() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`. Find out what arguments you should be passing to that function.

Comment: yes, I was trying:Definition: api.item_lookup(self, item_id, **params)
Docstring:
Given an Item identifier, the ``ItemLookup`` operation returns some or
all of the item attributes, depending on the response group specified
in the request. By default, ``ItemLookup`` returns an item's ``ASIN``,
``DetailPageURL``, ``Manufacturer``, ``ProductGroup``, and ``Title`` of
the item.

``ItemLookup`` supports many response groups, so you can retrieve many
different kinds of product information, called item attributes,
including product reviews, variations, similar products, pricing,

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see if function definition is `(self, item_id, **params)` then you have to provide `item_id` argument (`self` is `api`). You though have provided an `id` one which thus went to `params` dictionary leaving `item_id` without a value.

My best guess is that you have to just substitute `id` with `item_id` here, but I may be wrong and you have to take `item_id` from somewhere else.

Comment: was trying api.item_lookup(item_id = 'B007R07BK8') -- got InvalidParameterValue: ('ItemId', 'B007R07BK8')

Comment: @OlegTarasenko It just means that my guess is false and you have to get `item_id` elsewhere. But I never used amazon API bindings and thus can’t say anything beside what I already said. Some quick searching reveals that `B007R07BK8` looks like ASIN.